# Is the drainTo() method of a BlockingQueue atomic?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

If I do something like:

```
List<Object> list= new ArrayList<Object>();
queue.drainTo(list); //BlockingQueue
```

Am I assured that other threads can not *put* or *take* elements from the queue while *drainTo()* is being executed?

Otherwise, should I lock the whole queue before calling *drainTo()*?

Comment: I think you mean thread-safe instead of atomic? it is thread-safe, but not atomic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607195/thread-safety-of-blockingqueues-drainto-method

Comment: No, I meant atomic. So if I do not want any concurrent put and get in the queue (which are thread-safe, but I do not want them), I have no other solution than locking the whole queue? Thanks.

Comment: You might be able to wrap the queue in an [AtomicReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) - use `compareAndSet` to swap the current queue with a new queue, then other threads can continue to use the empty queue while the `drainTo` executes.