# Does Hazelcast IQueue drainTo lock the queue?

Tags: java, multithreading, hazelcast

I'm working on a distributed system, written in Java, which is using a Hazelcast [`IQueue`](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.12/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IQueue.html) ([non Javadoc documentation](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/3.12/data-structures/queue)). I am using Hazelcast 3.12, and for business reasons, do not have the ability to change this version.

One one node, I have a thread calling [`poll`](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.12/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IQueue.html#poll-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-). In another thread on that **same node**, I am calling [`drainTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html?is-external=true#drainTo-java.util.Collection-), a method in the `BlockingQueue` interface that `IQueue` implements.

The behavior I expect to see is that any thread calling `poll` (on the same node, or on a different node in the distributed system) does not see the same queue elements that I get in the `drainTo` call. What I instead see is that sometimes, the thread that's running `poll` sees an element that's also in the `drainTo` call.

I *don't* see this behavior if I swap out the Hazelcast `IQueue` with an undistributed `LinkedBlockingQueue`. This makes sense given the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6607195/1473320).

My questions are:

- Am I wrong in expecting that the contract of `BlockingQueue` includes this "exclusivity" in the elements seen when calling `poll` and `drainTo` in different threads?
- Is there a way to get all the elements of the queue at once such that I never see any duplicate elements in this "multiple consumers" scenario?

Comment: Maybe something else is going on but what you described is not expected. If you have a reproducer better to create an issue here: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/new/choose

Comment: Definitely, it should work similar to LinkedBlockingQueue. A reproducer would help to understand.